# Можно ли создать div не квадратный

Tags: canvas, html, javascript, css

Я хочу создать поле с квадратами (будет канвас), но повернутыми, и тогда вместо квадратов будут трапеции и параллелограммы. Мне надо создать div, чтоб он был в форме трапеции (потом повешу на них    `onclick="Функция()"`). Если это возможно, дайте пример как сделать 1 такой div, или подскажите где искать информацию про это.

Comment: А вопрос как закрыть,или пометить как отвеченый?

Comment: Нужно чтобы ответ был) на ответе тыкаеш принят(галочка) мы тут в коментах перечепятываемсо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CSS3 Shapes](http://www.css3shapes.com/) там есть трапеция

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо)